# Exception to Context Path in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

I am building a Spring Boot and Thymeleaf application with the custom context path:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/myapp
```

So the application can be accessed as:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp
```

All content is served on the `/myapp` context path, except for one mapping for a special case which needs to be:

```
http://localhost:8080/exception
```

Is there a way to make an exception to the custom context path for this special case?

Comment: No. As the context-path is globally for the whole application. You would need another standalone service mapped to that URL. Or abandon the user of a context path and put that prefix in all your controllers (which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Context-path is globally for the whole application, but still, there are two ways to archive what you want-

1. You can put your Context-path to all the controllers across the application manually, that way you can exclude your exception end-point from Context-path.
2. You can create a second Dispatcher-Servlet this way you can host your other end-point on a different port.

I personally won't prefer any of the above solutions as the first one is not suitable for a large application and the second solution adds extra complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I went with the route of manually applying the root context path to all controllers and html docs. I added a custom variable in application.properties with the root, and made a BaseController with `@RequestMapping(value = "${custom-root-path}")` so that I can set it in one place and apply everywhere.